# Remover tags HTML

Tags: c#, regex

Em questão de eficacia e desempenho, qual desses códigos é a melhor opção para remover tags HTML em uma string?

**Opção 1:**

```
string ss = "<b><i>The tag is about to be removed</i></b>";
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\<[^\\>]*\\>");
        Response.Write(String.Format("<b>Before:</b>{0}", ss)); // HTML Text
        Response.Write("<br/>");
        ss = regex.Replace(ss, String.Empty);
        Response.Write(String.Format("<b>After:</b>{0}", ss));// Plain Text as a OUTPUT
```

[Fonte](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136704/Remove-all-the-HTML-tags-and-display-a-plain-text)

**Opção 2:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Methods to remove HTML from strings.
/// </summary>
public static class HtmlRemoval
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML from string with Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
    {
    return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compiled regular expression for performance.
    /// </summary>
    static Regex _htmlRegex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML from string with compiled Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsRegexCompiled(string source)
    {
    return _htmlRegex.Replace(source, string.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove HTML tags from string using char array.
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
    {
    char[] array = new char[source.Length];
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    bool inside = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        char let = source[i];
        if (let == '<')
        {
        inside = true;
        continue;
        }
        if (let == '>')
        {
        inside = false;
        continue;
        }
        if (!inside)
        {
        array[arrayIndex] = let;
        arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
    return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }
}
```

[Fonte](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags)

Comment: Melhor opção considerando quais aspectos?

Comment: Prefiro a primeira opção. O código é mais enxuto e eu confio mais na regex de lá no que de match non-greedy :P

Opinião pessoal.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eficácia e desempenho...

Comment: Bom, então coloque isso claramente na pergunta, senão vira algo opinativo.

Comment: Ok, estou editando.

Comment: fugindo um pouco da pergunta, se você procura performance já pensou em fazer isso sem expressões regulares?

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett não consegui pensar em uma boa solução sem expressões regulares...

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UZzVJj - Não é EXATAMENTE como a sua expressão regular, que requer um "match" entre "<" e ">", mas esse código utiliza 0.016s da CPU segundo o Fiddle, isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: muito bom @LeonardoBosquett se você puder postar como resposta, é uma boa solução também...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiz um Fiddle para o primeiro caso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPUdtm). Os tempos foram:

```
Compile:    0.062s
Execute:    0s
Memory :    8kb
CPU    :    0.047s
```

[Fiz um Fiddle para o segundo caso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z6qICo). Para o método `HtmlRemoval.StripTagsRegex()`, os tempos foram:

```
Compile:    0.109s
Execute:    0s
Memory :    16kb
CPU    :    0.094s
```

Para o método `HtmlRemoval.StripTagsRegexCompiled()`, os tempos foram:

```
Compile:    0.063s
Execute:    0.031s
Memory :    16kb
CPU    :    0.109s
```

Para o método `HtmlRemoval.StripTagsCharArray()`, os tempos foram:

```
Compile:    1.969s
Execute:    0.016s
Memory :    16kb
CPU    :    0.703s
```

## Conclusão

Todos são igualmente eficazes.

O primeiro é, sem dúvida, o mais rápido, mas não é organizado quanto o segundo.

Os testes que fiz não consideram cadeias de caracteres muito grandes. Para cadeias pequenas, o teste serve bem. Para cadeias maiores, seria interessante estabelecer outros critérios e outros testes.

Comment: só posso votar daqui 4hs, rsrsrs...
Muito obrigado por sua resposta. Abriu os meus olhos quanto ao Fiddle também, eu não havia percebido a capacidade de obter essas informações. Mas por que o primeiro não é organizado?

Comment: Porque no segundo eu troco uma função e a abordagem da expressão regular muda completamente, já que tudo está envelopado e pronto para uso. No primeiro, eu tenho que configurar a expressão regular na mão, instanciar a expressão regular, executar e colocar o resultado em outra *string*.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando o desempenho, também pode ser feito a remoção das tags evitando o uso de expressões regulares, o que aumenta muito o desempenho, aqui está um código inicial (simples).

https://dotnetfiddle.net/UZzVJj

resultados do teste:

```
 Compile:   0.189s 
 Execute:   0s 
 Memory:    0b 
 CPU:       0.016s
```

Ele não faz **exatamente** a mesma regra que a expressão regular `\<[^\>]*\>`, pois esta remove somente se houver ambas as tags, < e >.